# cannot install anything from the software center (untrusted packages)

Tags: software-center

I am very new to Ubuntu and am pretty much using it as a refuge from Windows 10.

This being said I really have no prior knowledge in Ubuntu or anything computer related. I've had this problem for a while now, and I know it's probably user error, where I can't download anything from software center because it says the packages are untrusted (I have looked into some of the other threads that answer similar questions, none of their solutions seem to work), and when I hit okay when a popup with the options of repair or 'ok' appears and the installation stops; when I hit repair the popup re-opens repeatedly and seems to install a whole lot of packages that have no effect on the computer or the installation. Hitting 'ok' ends the installation with nothing having been installed.

Also, just as a note: this is the second time I'm asking this question. I know I'm probably not supposed to re-post the same thing twice but it's been a few weeks now and other then getting a very nice edit the post went untouched. This problem is the only reason I'm here, and I could really use the help.

Software Center Popup:
[image]

Terminal error:
[image]

[**Output of `sudo apt-key list`**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16391205/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we found out in our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/39751'), the problem was due to 11 missing keys and 2 unwanted keys.

Remove the unwanted keys (Chromium and Steam) with : `sudo apt-key del B05498B7 4E5E17B5`

Import the missing keys with :

```
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <all missing keys in the warning>`
```

Update the repositories : `sudo apt-get update`